# What happened at the end of the movie?

Tags: captain-harlock

I haven't seen the original series of *Captain Harlock*, however I recently watched the [movie](http://myanimelist.net/anime/17269/Captain_Harlock) during our most recent [Weekend Anime Extra](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2767/17758).

I feel like I followed along with the plot pretty well, and understood where the story was the whole time... That is until we got to the last few minutes and everything I knew just went out the window. So, it seems everyone just came back to life and the legend of Captain Harlock is going to continue, but why?

Basically, I'm looking for an explanation of what happened at the end. Why did everyone come back to life?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Harlock activates the detonators each time and he dies, and logan is replacing him. At this point if you didn't understood, logan is harlock. Although this time, he did not activate the detonators by seeing logan (his younger self) eager for life and merelly having the same dream harlock once had for earth and humanity. At this point, he's steping back in command allowing logan to lead arcadia and the crew. That's why you see 2 of them in the end, and that's why the crew revived and the dark matter came back.

The movie gave you a big hint at the start by saying:
"Far, far in the future... Or perhaps, the distant past..."

Hope it solved the trouble you had with the ending.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, after the Arcadia has crash-landed on earth, a fleet arrives and signals "This is the Solar Federation, ...".
The Solar Federation has been non-existent for 100 years in the main plot. This already tells you all you need to know.